# PermissionError when creating mkvirtualenv for cuckoo

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to setup Venv for cuckoo sandbox but when I run this command

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 cuckoo-test
```

i get that error
PS: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExudR.png)

i tried to setup another venv folder i get same error using

```
$mkvirtualenv name
```

any ideas how to fix

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].